# Распространение вирусов по сети

Tags: сервер, безопасность, вирусы

К примеру, если взять вирус `WannaCry`, он распространяется  по сети через открытые порты..  Точнее через SMB.

Вопрос: не достаточно же просто открытых портов? разве еще не нужен постоянный `ip`?? а у большей части пользователей серый `ip`...  как же тогда вирусы заражают через сеть..

PS я знаю, что можно скачать файл, и запустить вирус... имеется ввиду именно заражение через сеть

Answer (score 2):

Итак, давайте уточним.
Вирусы не распространяются по портам, а SMB - протокол, который используется какими-нибудь программами или компонентами. Вирус распространяется в следствии того, что в программе, которая принимает и/или обрабатывает какие либо данные (например, по протоколу SMB), есть уязвимость, использовав которую, например, можно выполнить вредоносный код.

Существует масса возможных способов передачи и обработки данных. Вы же когда скачиваете фильм через торрент не открываете порт? Не покупаете статический IP-адрес?

Предположим, что в Ваш любимый BitTorrent-клиент имеет функцию автоматической разархивации данных. Вот скачиваете Вы архив, а он сразу же и распаковывается. Прелесть, не правда ли? И вот есть косяк, что если имя файла начинается с последовательности `7#♦2☺2♀╒47`, то он запускает этот файл.

Вот хакеры увидели эту уязвимость, забацали программу-вирус и начали её раскидывать по интернетам. И все пользователи, у которых этот косячный BitTorrent-клиент скачав этот файл автоматически заразились этим вирусом. А вирус этот в свою очередь просканил компьютеры, которые находятся в Вашей локальной сети (а если это мед учреждение, то там может быть под сотню компьютеров, объединённых в локальную сеть) и начал проверять, не запущено ли на этом компьютере программы, которая будет иметь похожую как Ваш BitTorrent-клиент уязвимость. Нашёл, воспользовался. И так дальше, дальше и дальше.

Это, конечно, очень условный пример. Но суть должна быть ясна.

Вопрос очень абстрактный, есть множество способов передачи и обработки информации в сети, множество различных протоколов.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ! Но не понятно: компьютеру нельзя просто так взять и отправить данные, правильно? Должна быть программа, которая слушает определенный порт... разве не так?

Comment: Конечно, я про это и говорил. Эта программа может быть частью операционной системы. Например, какая-нибудь служба, управляющая домашними группами, или Центр обновления виндовс или вообще что угодно.

Comment: получается, обычного юзера заразить не вариант тем же WannaCry?  у которого серый ip... имею ввиду из сети

Comment: Вероятность есть всегда. Всё зависит от используемого программного обеспечения и то, как оно обменивается данными. К слову, данными можно обмениваться не только Peer-to-Peer. Ещё раз повторю, что не играет роли тот факт, что у Вас серый ip адрес, когда вы скачиваете и раздаёте торренты